# Load a C# WPF form inside a library from a CLI C++ application

Tags: c#, c++, .net, c, wpf

I have a dll file written in C# that is in the same solution as my application which is written in C++ with some files set to compile under the /cli flag. I'd like to load the WPF form inside my C# dll and display it in the C++ /cli application.

I already have my C++ application configured to display WPF content, as I am currently programatically adding controls onto the WPF form but I have not been able to find out how to load a form from an external resource at runtime.

Comment: Is your C# assembly a WPF (User/Custom) Control that contains a WPF Window?

Comment: @gliderkite Yes, that's correct. And in my C++ application I a native thread which calls an STA managed thread. From the STA managed thread I want to load the form from the WPF control library and display it.

Comment: It's setup like that because parts of the application require native startup.

Comment: If you added the control reference to your CLI project, you should be able to have access to your control, so have you tried with [Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.show.aspx) or [ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx) methods?

Comment: Post is an an answer, it worked. I just added the namespace to my project and used this code: appHandle->Run(cliLicenseWindow) where cliLicenseWindow is the name of my C# window. @gliderkite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you added the control reference to your CLI project, you should be able to have access to your control; having application handle use [ApplicationHandle->Run(YourWindow)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597011.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

You can load an external DLL into your project like this

```
Dim assembly As Assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(libraryPath & "filename.dll")
Dim type As Type = assembly.[GetType]("NameSpace.ClassName")

// i'm loading as a form here but can be any control
Dim frm As Form = TryCast(Activator.CreateInstance(type), Form)
```

one final note, if you're loading a class or control inside the loaded form (above) that resides also inside the same assembly you also need to load it first before calling it in the form